# Xdebug installation and setup

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, xdebug

I have moved everything to a different server and everything is running successfully except today (and I have spent ALL day) I have attempted the wholly dreaded task of setting up XDebug.

I have read the instructions and gone through them 3 times.
I note it now ends with the very unhelpful

> Please also update php.ini files in adjacent directories, as your
> system seems to be configured with a separate php.ini file for the web
> server and command line.

I have finally got it to appear in my [phpinfo](https://51.89.139.204/phpinfo.php) however it does not seem to connect, and I cannot see it listening on the port

[image]

At

/etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini

and

/etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini

I have

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = /usr/lib/php/20210902/xdebug.so
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_port = 9003
;xdebug.client_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.log = "/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey = PHPSTORM
#[/xdebug]#
```

On PHPStorm (which I don't think is the issue as it was working on previous server)
[image]

I have added xdebug_info() to start of php code and now [getting this output](https://51.89.139.204/xdebuginfo.php)

[image]

log shows

```
[1147] Log opened at 2023-07-16 15:22:03.120035
[1147] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: localhost:9003.
[1147] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for 'localhost:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[1147] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: localhost:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).
[1147] Log closed at 2023-07-16 15:22:03.121645
```

Additionally I can see phpstorm listening with
[image]
[image]

Access is only via SSH, in putty I have

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this further please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xdebug does **not** listen. It is the IDE that must listen for incoming connections **from** Xdebug. It is therefore normal that you seen nothing listening until you enable "Listen for Connections" in PhpStorm.

If it shows up in `phpinfo()` then it will be loaded. If you use `xdebug_info()` it tells you which modes are enabled as well. And because you have `start_with_request` turned on, it will also tell you whether it made a successful connection to your IDE, or if not, why not. Each warning/error messages in the Diagnostics Log has a link to documentation with further information.

To see even more diagnostics information, that, when you read it should clarify what is going on, enable `xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log` and `xdebug.log_level=10` in `php.ini`. These settings will, after restarting your webserver, also reflect in the `xdebug_info()` output.

Comment: thanks, used your helpful info to refine the question, as per xdebug_info output at the bottom

Comment: That means that PhpStorm is not listening. After you put it in "Listen for incoming debug connections" mode, does it then show up in your `netstat` output? It is possible that it is listening in IPv6 mode only. If that's the case, use `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` as value to `xdebug.client_host` (or comment it out, as that is the default).

Comment: I have commented it out, and also checked Phpstorm is listening, which it is

Comment: Is there a firewall involved? `iptables -v -L` will tell you. Can you `telnet` to `localhost 9003` ?

Comment: Just checking - when you mention localhost, I am trying to remote debug

Comment: You didn't say that... You must then give the value of your local IP address as value to `xdebug.client_host`, or, if you are on the same local network, you can set `xdebug.discover_client_host=1` (but don't do that if your dev server is directly accessible over the internet).

Comment: sorry, for the confusion, so when you say the local ip address, you mean the ip address local to the server (eg the remote host ?). The local host in respect to phpstorm is a laptop so unpredictable.

Comment: also is there any single place I should make these changes, I am currently duplicating at /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini and /etc/php/8.1/fpm/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini (note for others reading these paths will vary depending on OS / php version)

Comment: for clarity: local is my dev laptop, remote is the server on the internet. Both firewalls off and with xdebug.client_host = <WANIP /> there is no change - [11123] [Step Debug] INFO: Connecting to configured address/port: <WANIP />:9003.
[11123] [Step Debug] WARN: Creating socket for '<WANIP />:9003', poll success, but error: Operation now in progress (29).
[11123] [Step Debug] ERR: Could not connect to debugging client. Tried: <WANIP />:9003 (through xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254527/discussion-between-datadimension-and-derick).

Comment: I am accepting this just due to the commitment from Derick and the statement 'xdebug does not listen'. This points to the client. And while I thought I had covered everything, I realised that as I had locked down the server so much to SSH only (not a bad thing) I realised that PHPStorm could only go through an SSH tunnel. This needs to be configured through Putty and an active putty session to the server to debug, again for security not a bad thing either.